# Black color shadow not showing - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, shadow

I am working on an app where I have a header on top and a scroll view below it. Now, I want to add a bottom shadow to the header. The background color for the app is black. The shadow on the header stops working when I keep the color as black or gray. It works for other colors. I want that when the scroll view is scrolled and items go beyond view, the header to show a fade kind of thing above the scroll view items instead of a hard line.

You can see the intended effect with blue shadow. But, with a black shadow, it doesn't work.

[image: shadow showing with blue color]

[image: shadow not showing with black color]

Here is the test code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct BackButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("test")
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
                .resizable()
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .heavy, design: .rounded))
                .frame(width: 14, height: 20)
        }
        .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
}

struct NavHeader: View {
    
    var title: String = "NavHeader"
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            BackButton()
                .padding(.horizontal)
            Spacer()
        }
        .overlay {
            Text(self.title)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .semibold))
        }
    }
}

struct Item: View {
    let image: String
    
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            Circle()
                .fill(.white)
                .opacity(0.13)
                .frame(width: 59, height: 59)
            Image(systemName: image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(height: 36)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavHeader()
                .padding(.vertical)
                .background(Color.black.shadow(color:.black, radius: 4, y:8))
            
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack{
                    Item(image: "house.fill")
                    Item(image: "candybarphone")
                    Item(image: "music.note")
                    Item(image: "map.fill")
                }.padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MainView()
            .background(Color.black)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using this to create your shadow, right?

```
NavHeader()
    .padding(.vertical)
    .background(Color.black.shadow(color:.black, radius: 4, y:8))
```

Why don't you just do that:

```
NavHeader()
    .padding(.vertical)
    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 4, y: 8)
```

Not sure if it's going to work, but maybe?

If you need that background there, you can try this:

```
NavHeader()
    .padding(.vertical)
    .background {
        Color.black
    }
    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 4, y: 8)
```

Comment: Without the background, the shadow is applied to the elements in the HStack, instead of the container. Using the background and shadow separately doesn't make any difference here and the problem still remains

Comment: black shadow on black color?

Comment: yeah, the shadow won't show on the background, but when the scroll view items cross the frame, there should be a black fade over those items. Thus, a shadow on the header. You can see the intended effect in the image with blue shadow.